# how to access another app using basic authentication

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, basic-authentication

I have a Rails application and when we click on a link in my app, I want to open new tab and load another application by Basic Authentication via JQuery and AJAX. The new application is exposed in some other server.

my Gem file as follows.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby "2.3.3"

gem 'couchrest', '~> 1.2', '>= 1.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.0.5'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 5.0.5'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0.6'
gem 'sprockets', '~> 3.6.3'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.4'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
gem 'couchrest_model', '~> 2.0.4'
gem 'tzinfo-data', '~> 1.2016.6', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw]
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'rake', '< 11.0'
gem 'pg', '~> 0.19.0'
#gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4'
gem 'sendgrid-ruby', '~> 0.0.3'
gem 'twilio-ruby', '~> 4.2.1'
gem 'sassc'
gem 'open_uri_redirections'

group :development, :test, :ci do
gem 'byebug', '~> 8.2.1'
gem 'dotenv-rails', '~> 2.0.2'
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.3.2'
gem 'timecop', '~> 0.8.0'
end

group :development do
gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'
gem 'spring', '~> 1.5.0'
end

group :production do
  gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3'
end
```

my JavaScript file snippet..

```
$.ajax
    ({
          type: "POST",
          url: "external_URL",
          beforeSend : function(req) {
                req.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Basic ' +             
  Base64.encode(unm + ':' + pwd));
          },
          success: function (){
            alert('Thanks for your comment!'); 
          },
          error: function (jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
          debugger
            alert('error!'); 
          }
    });
```

I am getting some error as follows,

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'external_URL' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.

I have tested the same by enabling/disabling CORS plugin.

Comment: Did you configure `rack-cors` gem properly as mentioned here: https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors ?

Comment: Your code of rails application is fine just make sure to add certain rules for requests you are performing. In order to do that you have to setup CORS policy, not in the main application but in the application, you are requesting.